# Webwork Supports Wild Card in xwork.xml?

Tags: struts2, webwork

My question is, does Webwork supports wild card in its configuration file xwork.xml?.

Example:

```
------
Can we write :

<action name="login_*" class="com.xyz.LoginAction" method="{1}">
  ------------
</action>
```

I know struts2 supports it, but my question is related to webwork.

Comment: If you have a webwork based app, then why don't you just try that?

Comment: if tried like above. but not working, also did RND, but not getting exact answer it supports or not. I thought like, it may be any way of writing it in webwork.